# How to return a random parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, random

```
Template<typename T>
T Choose(T x, T y, T z)
{
  //What code do i write so that when Choose() is called it would randomly 
  // return x y or z?

   return;
}
```

For example if x=2, y=ten and z=4 then it would chose neither 2, ten or 4 to return

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Have you looked at all at c++'s random library?

Answer (score 1):

Place all your parameters in a list.  Pick a random number from start of list to end of list and return that parameter.  Note, I am not familiar with writing `C++` so please forgive the `C#` code here.  This should be enough to give you an idea on how to complete this.

```
 //Place all params in an array
 var params = [x,y,z];

 //Instantiate random number generator
 var r = new Random();

 //use 0 for min and 2 for max in this example and return 
 //the random array position
 return params[r.Next(int min, int max)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

Template<typename T>
T Choose(T x, T y, T z)
{
    std::array<T*,3> temp{&x,&y,&z}; // or use std::reference_wrapper instead
    auto rand_index=std::rand() % temp.size();
    return *temp[rand_index];
}
```

Comment: `% 3` not 4, or better: `temp.size()`.

Comment: Or even better with `std::uniform_int_distribution` from `<random>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yup that is better